# How to set alias in pushbots for phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, pushbots

I am using pushbots and trying to set an alias for my device, I could not find any code in the documentation to do so. I tried using below code

```
var Pushbots = PushbotsPlugin.initialize("569a8967177959f4778b4567", {
     "android":{
                "sender_id":"117196338125"
               }
    });
Pushbots.updateAlias("Test");
```

but it doesn't work. My device is showing up but without any alias

Comment: Please paste your code

Comment: This might help you https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/phonegap-sdk-integration

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is probably that `updateAlias` function is being executed
>   immediately before device is fully registered. Try to set time out for
>   30 seconds or a minute before you set the alias and see if it works or try to put your code when you received your registration id.

```
Pushbots.on("registered", function(token){
    console.log("Registration Id:" + token);
    Pushbots.updateAlias("Test");
});
```

you can check similar thread [here.](https://github.com/pushbots/phonegap/issues/3)